# HTTPS Urls don't work in chat previews

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

The chat does not show a preview of comments, answers, questions etc when you use the `https://` protocol with the URL. Some browsers default to `https` instead, those users must manually change the URL string to get a preview, which is slightly annoying.

Answer (score 6):

Note that historically this was correct: only the `http://` address existed - and the current situation is that `https://` is *provided* by Stack Exchange, but only `http://` is *supported*. But sure; we should fix that. And (waves [magic wand](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)) *already have*. Note that while we now *recognise* `https://` addresses, we *link* to the supported location, i.e. `http://`. I will make a second change shortly to emit protocol-relative links instead of http or https.

Update: the rendered links should now be protocol-relative.