# HTTPS Twitter links don't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

This is similar to [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268293/https-urls-dont-work-in-chat-previews).

[Evidence](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22315277#22315277).

Not sure if the case of just Twitter or other sites too.

Comment: The most gripping one is xkcd...

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes, it should.